# How can I easily parse an ISO 8601 duration/period in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, iso8601

Is there an easy/inbuilt way to convert ISO 8601 durations/periods within Oracle?

So let's say I want to turn `PT0H4M51S` into the number of seconds - is there a way to do this without writing my own parser/code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Leo mentioned in comments, you can use [the `to_dsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions220.htm), which accepts ISO formats (up to days; months and years can be handled by [`to_yminterval()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions231.htm) instead); but that gives you an [`INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#r14c1-t3):

```
select to_dsinterval('PT0H4M51S')
from dual;

DURATION  
-----------
0 0:4:51.0
```

You could convert that to interval seconds with [the `extract` function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm):

```
with t as (
  select to_dsinterval('PT0H4M51S') as duration
  from dual
)
select (extract (day from duration) * 86400)
  + (extract (hour from duration) * 3600)
  + (extract (minute from duration) * 60)
  + extract (second from duration) as seconds
from t;

   SECONDS
----------
       291
```

If you only have a time duration - so it can't be longer than a day - then you could use date manipulation instead:

```
select (to_date('PT0H4M51S', '"PT"HH24"H"MI"M"SS"S"')
 - trunc(sysdate, 'MM')) * 86400 as seconds
from dual;

   SECONDS
----------
       291
```

If you convert a string containing just a time to a `DATE` type in Oracle, it defaults to the first day of the current month. And `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` gives you midnight the first day of the current month. The difference is the duration in fractions of a day, so multiply by 60*60*24 to get the difference in seconds.

But you have to supply the fixed text parts (P, T, H, M and S) as quoted literals, so you'd have to know exactly the format you're going to receive. The `to_dsinterval()` version will work with any valid format.

Comment: ISO standard allows formats what is not supported by this fuction. Example: `select TO_DSINTERVAL('P5Y') from dual;` It is failing.

Comment: @takacsot - it is, but `select TO_YMINTERVAL('P5Y') from dual;` works. That generates an `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` value, your example tries to generate an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value, so "ORA-01867: the interval is invalid" is correct. [Oracle has two interval data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00200).

Comment: Does it mean that I have to parse the format first to know which parse method to use? Not so logical :)

Comment: Yes, essentially, if you don't know what data you expect; and you can't have a single interval that includes both YM and DS (I guess partly because '5 years' or '3 months' can be a variable number of days, though who knows how Oracle decided this), and you can't combine YM and DS intervals into one - unless you do, somehow, convert the YM to an arbitrary number of days.

Comment: It's the same as in recent `java.time.Duration` versus `java.time.Period`. Community seems to largely decide that the right way to treat time spans is to have two distinct types.